# Google-App-Script vs php in encoding base64

Tags: php, google-apps-script, base64, encode, hmac

This php code decodes the secret key before hashing with SHA 512

```
$API_SECRET_KEY="W0+m0Dc9GMN9yDVeq3GMDsJ49WasEhQHkNHNuDw3wNg=";
$BDAPI_SECRET_KEY=base64_decode($API_SECRET_KEY);
$HMAC_SIGN = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512',$MESSAGE,$BDAPI_SECRET_KEY,true));
echo $HMAC_SIGN;

BfVNi21gY09c8M18cWBRBgo1W9pAlXM99ZVoF7Kz2ETFnIuvXjj8NRvRgn/GaT/m6YJ8efsr5s9EDbIhznAaag==
```

I want to replicate this in google app script

```
var Secret = "W0+m0Dc9GMN9yDVeq3GMDsJ49WasEhQHkNHNuDw3wNg="  
var BDSecret= Utilities.base64Decode(Secret)
var hmac = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, message, BDSecret ));
    Logger.log(hmac)

ew5KhLWSJixn8zw4s6VkpYIwvGBjrmjY3LhNWZr9CVEw6W22LOGg+lVzA3uQgOVyICSCffw2bzTepnBdoYtldw==
```

If I do not decode the API before hashing they return the same result. But for this particular purpose, the key needs to be decoded. The message variable is just my first name "Parit" in case someone wants to replicate.

Comment: are they the same when you log the key after Base64 decoding? could it be a utf8/non-utf8 issue?

Comment: echo $BDAPI_SECRET_KEY; return the same as Logger.log(Utilities.newBlob(BDSecret).getDataAsString());

Comment: Do you need `Utilities.newBlob(BDSecret).getDataAsString()` to get `BDSecret` as a string? if so, shouldn't it be in the `computeHmacSignature` arguments too (according to doc, key argument is a string)? Another thing you can try is to give a fourth argument to `computeHmacSignature` to try to specify another charset

Comment: you are right, GAS decode into source octet array while php decode into  text (ASCII). Problem is that some source octet are negative, which does not translate to anything in ASCII.

Comment: [91, 79, -90, -48, 55, 61, 24, -61, 125, -56, 53, 94, -85, 113, -116, 14, -62, 120, -11, 102, -84, 18, 20, 7, -112, -47, -51, -72, 60, 55, -64, -40]

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: By recent Google's update, the byte array can be used for ``Utilities.computeHmacSignature()``. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2):

I thought that `Utilities.computeHmacSignature()` might not be able to use []byte for the value. So as a workaround, how about using jsSHA? I think that in your case, you can use https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/blob/master/src/sha512.js.

The flow for using jsSHA is as follows.

#### Flow :

1. Download sha512.js.
2. On script editor, create new script as for example, the filename of `sha512.js`.

   - Copy and paste the script of sha512.js to the created script.
3. Copy and paste the sample script to `Code.gs` of the script editor.
4. Run `myFunction()` of the sample script.

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var message = "Parit";
  var secret = "W0+m0Dc9GMN9yDVeq3GMDsJ49WasEhQHkNHNuDw3wNg=";
  var obj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
  obj.setHMACKey(secret, "B64");
  obj.update(message);
  Logger.log(obj.getHMAC("B64"))
}
```

#### Note :

- When I tested `Parit` for `message`, I got `BfVNi21gY09c8M18cWBRBgo1W9pAlXM99ZVoF7Kz2ETFnIuvXjj8NRvRgn/GaT/m6YJ8efsr5s9EDbIhznAaag==`.

It this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

### Update :

[By the Google's update at June 19, 2018](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#june_19_2018), `Utilities.computeHmacSignature()` got to be able to use the byte arrays. By this, using only native Google Apps Scvript, the result can be retrieved without using jsSHA. So I would like to update my answer.

#### Modified script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var message = "Parit";
  var secret = "W0+m0Dc9GMN9yDVeq3GMDsJ49WasEhQHkNHNuDw3wNg=";

  var value = Utilities.base64Decode(Utilities.base64Encode(message));
  var key = Utilities.base64Decode(secret);
  var out = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, value, key);
  var res = Utilities.base64Encode(out)
  Logger.log(res)
}
```

#### Result :

```
BfVNi21gY09c8M18cWBRBgo1W9pAlXM99ZVoF7Kz2ETFnIuvXjj8NRvRgn/GaT/m6YJ8efsr5s9EDbIhznAaag==
```

Comment: Thank you.  This solution worked for me.  The GAS code (`Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512...`) does not produce the same signature as a few other libraries I've tried.

Comment: @pomo Yes. I also had the same situation. So I used this method. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @pomo By recent Google's update, the byte array can be used for ``Utilities.computeHmacSignature()``. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?