# How can I use the library Utilitites in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-apps-script, utilities

```
    const signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(
        Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_1,
        signatureBaseString,
        this.getSigningKey()
    );
```

This is an example of what I need to implement in typescript but I need to replace the library Utilities.

A solution for the computeHmacSignature in typescript.

Comment: Maybe this question relative to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369714/hmac-in-node-js-crypto-vs-google-apps-script-gas